# How to find amount of cells?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

how to find amount of cells in Marza column with value <30% but only if second column (Sklep) have value "Gdansk"?

https://ibb.co/mRBNVLB

Answer (score 2):

You can use `COUNTIFS`:

```
=COUNTIFS(B6:B18,"Gdansk",F6:F18,"<30%")
```

Answer (score 1):

1. select your table
2. make it an excel table
3. add the filters you want to the marza column
4. right click on a cell in the just created table and click "add total row"
5. in the total row, select the cell that corresponds to the column you want (Marza)
6. a little drop down arrow should appear to the right of the cell, click it, select "count"

This will count the amount of cells in a column, and it will automatically deal with filters.

Alternatively, you could use Excel's `=COUNTIF()` function.

If you do not understand what I mean, I recommend you watch this short tutorial: [Excel 2016 - Tables - Creating, Sorting, Filtering](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xJ4OSVXv71g)